# Which version of d20 is World of Warcraft RPG compatible with?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, d20-system, warcraft-tabletop-rpg

I picked up the WoW RPG a few years back before I knew anything about D&D/d20 and am just now getting around to checking out D&D and am wondering where this book fits into the d20 versions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

World of Warcraft Second Revision (which is the edition that I have myself) is compatible with 3e/3.5e d20.

I've actually used a few ideas/concepts/classes from those sourcebooks in my 3.5e D&D game.

Comment: Just noticed it was listed on Amazon as "World Of Warcraft The Roleplaying Game (d20 3.5)"

Answer (score 2):

3.5 is the version it was officially published with. It therefore has a degree of backwards compatibility with Pathfinder.

There is also an ongoing fan project to convert Warcraft into 5e--Here is a link. 
https://goo.gl/cmCypo

Comment: Could you disclose your relationship with this fan project? Are you an author, its creator, or an otherwise invested party? This answer presently reads largely as an advertisement for the fan conversion. Please read our advertising guidelines: [How to not be a spammer](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).

Comment: I see no reason to assume this user is spamming and not just linking a relevant resource.  Do disclose any affiliation to the project you have if any, though, please.